Can't resolve 'fs' in react app build stage
Not sure what's missing or what am i doing wrong, but I cannot get this library to work for the life of me
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "18.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.23.9",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "framer-motion": "^10.18.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "jsencrypt": "^3.3.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "node-forge": "^1.3.1",
    "node-rsa": "^1.1.1",
    "os": "^0.1.2",
    "package.json": "^2.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-cookie-consent": "^9.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.4",
    "react-native-svg": "^14.1.0",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.15.1",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.3.9",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.77.1",
    "sass-loader": "^14.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "BUILD_PATH='/m2-react/public-html-build/' react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

Not sure why can't it see it from dependencies npm install works all ok.
Is it something different, other library name or how does it work really?
Should this not be part of node.js anyway?

What exactly isn’t working?  It’s not clear what specific problem you’re trying to describe.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following:

Use a library like 'browser-fs' or 'file-saver' that provides a browser-friendly alternative to the 'fs' module.
Move the code that requires the 'fs' module to a Node.js environment, such as a server-side API or a script that runs during the build process.
Use a bundler like Webpack or Rollup to include the 'fs' module in your build, but be aware that this may not work as expected in a browser environment.

Here's an example of how you might use the 'browser-fs' library:
import { writeFile } from 'browser-fs';

writeFile('file.txt', 'Hello, world!', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File written successfully!');
  }
});```

Remember to install the 'browser-fs' library first by running npm install browser-fs or yarn add browser-fs in your terminal.

